# How can I merge cells in a table in Libreoffice Draw?

Tags: tables, merge, cell, libre-office

I am using Libre Office Draw to create a brochure. The brochure has tables, and those tables contains merged cells. I am able to create tables, however I cannot find any menu entry with the option to merge cells. Is there a way to merge cells in a table in Libre Office Draw? If yes, kindly mention.

The details about the Libre Office Draw program I am using, from it's About section is:

```
Version: 6.0.7.3
Build ID: 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.6
CPU threads: 4; OS: Linux 4.15; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3; 
Locale: en-IN (en_IN); Calc: group
```

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! Your question would be clearer if you had added an screenshot of your table whereyou want to merge cells ... But what has this to do with Graphic design? Would it not better to ask such a question on a site handling LibreOffice or MS Excel?

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider upvoting (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the accepted answer (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). That is the way here to say "Thank you for your help!"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's the problem, but in Windows you select a few adjacent cells and right click. One of the options is to Merge the selected cells.

[image]

The lower table is the result.

Merge is also in Format > Table menu. I have Libre Office Draw 6.2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

In LibreOffice Draw you use the same method you will use in other programs like LibreOffice Calc or MS Excel:

1. Insert the table you need.
2. Mark the two (or more cells) you want to merge (see red arrow marked with 1).
3. After you have moved the mouse coursor inside the marked cells do a right click. You get a new windows shown in screenshot, see red arrow marked with 2 (my version is in german, the marked blue line "Zelle" means "Cell").
4. Move the mouse cursor on the line "Zelle"/"Cell" and click to get the sub window, marked with red arrow with 3. The marked german "Zellen verbinden" means in english "merge cells" ...
5. Click on "Zellen verbinden"/"merge cells"  to merge the cells ...

It is the usual way in an system using windows for menu/sub menu: you have first to mark what you want to change (there is no other way you can tell the OS/programm what you want to change) and then you can call the context menu (right click) to get showed what is allowed by OS/program at the moment ... As far as I know there is no difference in this behaviour between MS Windows/MS Excel/Libre Office draw and Linux/Libre Office ...

See the following screenshot:

[image]